# Filtering the contents of a combobox based on the selection of another

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have 5 combo boxes. They each contain part of a Configuration Number. I would like them to update after one of them has been selected (narrowing down the options to the new set of possibilities).
I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997928/filtering-multiple-combobox-vb-net) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964981/filter-combobox-in-a-datgrid-based-on-another-combobox-vb-net). The first of which is entirely useless, and the second just leads to a dead end.

My current code for the event handler looks like this

```
Private Sub cbNumberOfModules_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbNumberOfModules.SelectedIndexChanged
    ReduceArrayOfConfigs(cbNumberOfModules.Text)
    cbNumResLeft.Items.Clear()
    cbNumResRight.Items.Clear()
    cbResLeft.Items.Clear()
    cbResRight.Items.Clear()
    BuildComboBoxSelectFunction(2)
End Sub
```

However this doesn't seem to be updating the Combo Boxes.

The function `ReduceArrayOfConfigs` simply siphons out the unwanted configuration numbers based on the choice of the user.
The `BuildComboBoxSelectFunction(2)` adds a set of possible values based on the configuration numbers in the reduced array.

My initial thought was if I clear the Combo Boxes I can then simply do `cb.Item.Add` and it will update them. I'm now assuming this is incorrect and I need to refresh them or something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what if you comment out BuildComboBoxSelectFunction(2) - does it then clear the text boxes?  I'm thinking that maybe it clears them, then repopulates with all the same stuff again

Comment: Oh my I'm stupid. That's what was going wrong. I was repoplulating with the same content because I stored the reduced array in a new array. Thanks!